# Why clang-tidy's deadcode.DeadStores raises warning in case of RAII with reference_wrapper usage?

Tags: c++, clang, clang-tidy

Code snippet:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class OnExit
{
public:
    explicit OnExit(const std::function<void()>& f):f_(f){}
    ~OnExit(){f_();}
private:
    std::function<void()> f_;
};

void finish(const bool& details)
{
    std::cout << "foo finished with " << std::boolalpha << details << std::endl;
}

int foo(int i)
{
    bool details = false;
    OnExit action{std::bind(&finish, std::cref(details))};
    if (i < 0)
    {
        throw 0;
    }

    if (i < 10)
    {
        return i;
    }
    int result = i*6;

    details = true;

    if (i < 100)
    {
        return result + 5;
    }

    details = false;
    return result*result;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo(5) << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo(20) << std::endl;
    try
    {
        std::cout << foo(-1) << std::endl;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "exception" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << foo(120) << std::endl;
}
```

So, function finish() is called everytime when program leave a scope of foo(). Value of variable 'details' is read and printed.

But... clang-tidy output:

```
2 warnings generated.
<<path>>/neverused.cpp:33:5: warning: Value stored to 'details' is never read [clang-analyzer-deadcode.DeadStores]
details = true;
^
<<path>>/neverused.cpp:33:5: note: Value stored to 'details' is never read
details = true;
^
<<path>>/neverused.cpp:40:5: warning: Value stored to 'details' is never read [clang-analyzer-deadcode.DeadStores]
details = false;
^
<<path>>/neverused.cpp:40:5: note: Value stored to 'details' is never read
details = false;
^
```

After changing std::bind to lambda, there is no warnings.
My question is: what is the magic behind bind and/or reference_wrapper and why clang-tidy doesn't understand it?

Comment: reference_wrapper effectively stores the address, and converts when the underlying function is called.  My guess is that clang-tidy is having trouble analyzing across the `std::bind()` for some reason.  My best guess is the use of the function pointer (vs. a function object).